# begginer s logic

Tags: logic

I came across this implication 
 $$ x<1+\frac{1}{n}, \forall n \implies x\leq 1 \tag{1}$$ But I find it strange that $x$ has no quantifiers. so I tried to re-write it in a way that I though would be more rigorous.
My first attempt was $$\forall n, x< 1+\frac{1}{n}\implies x\leq 1\tag{2}$$ But $(1)$ is equivalent to $$\forall n, (x< 1+\frac{1}{n} )\implies (x\leq 1)$$ (right?), which is utterly false.
Then I wrote  $$\forall x, ( \forall n, x<1+\frac{1}{n})\implies (x\leq 1)\tag{3}$$ which is a statement of the form $$\forall x, P(x)\implies Q(x)\tag{4}$$
My questions are: i) of $(1),(2),(3)$ or $(4)$, which are correct, if any? 
ii) More generally, when is the $\forall$ placed in front and when not?  (For example, if $(3)$ became $$\forall x, ( x<1+\frac{1}{n}, \forall n)\implies (x\leq 1),$$ would it be ok?

Comment: The " fully quantified" version is: $$\forall x\,\left(\left(\forall n\, x<1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\implies x\leq 1\right)$$

Comment: Also, don't get in the habit of writing $\forall n$ at the end of a sentence like this. $\forall$ is notation, not a shorthand for the words "for all."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I never know, is a colon required after $\forall n$?

Comment: That is a bit more variable, depending on the person. I used to put punctuation after $\forall n$, but a lot of people here don't, and I have since stopped. It does create spacing issues if you are not careful. Some people would say my parentheses are somewhat redundant, but I was being extra-careful to be clear. @Bye_World

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course (3) is correct. (2) is wrong as a matter of fact. However (1) is generally considered an acceptable form of the formally correct (3). Note that in (1) one puts $\forall n$ at the end. This is precisely done in order not to be confused with the wrong statement (2)

Comment: thank you for your answers. i understand that (1) is also accepted, as a compromise between writing correctly and writing fast?

Comment: @DanLeonte Yes, i would say so. In particular, the $x$ quantificator is considered unessential (or understood). Putting the quantificator on $n$ at the end of the antecedent rules out the possibility that $\forall n$ quantifies the whole implication (which gives the wrong interpretation (2)); in other words it is a way to stress that only the antecedent is quantified, without need to put parenthesis